# How to dynamically create db tables with code first in a prism wpf modular app?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, sqlite, prism

I'm using prism to build a modular app with pluggable modules.

I've already set up sqlite with EF successfully in a separate project to be included in each module.

BUT

I want my module to have a "Model" folder with classes required only by it, in a way that, when loaded by the wpf shell, the system will create db tables for it  (if they already don't exist).

How can I "inject" my model classes into the `DbContext` class at runtime like when I register views and viewmodels with UnityContainer?

Comment: See if this helps: https://aleemkhan.wordpress.com/2013/02/28/dynamically-adding-dbset-properties-in-dbcontext-for-entity-framework-code-first/

Comment: Why not have many small dbcontexts? and only use the one you need in the given module?

Comment: we worked on a big Modular project, we solved this problem by: - removing the model builder and creates utility to generate SQL scripts of models. - we handled the migration too. - and a base context as a based module context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use EF 6 you can try **modelBuilder.RegisterEntityType(type);** for adding new Entity in you context and you can handel migration configuration to add your entity. Also you can use **modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(assembly);** to add your Entity configuration to your context.
i have a modular web application in this way.
when my web application is started i check all modules and added the entities and shared entity to a context (BTW. some of modules have there own context) and migration do our changes to main database.

Answer (score 1):

T4 (Text Template Transformation Toolkit) is a tool which you can use it to generate DbContext automatically from your Model classes.

I will not write the whole code example because we have already a good example in the given link below:

https://www.paragon-inc.com/resources/blogs-posts/using-t4-to-generate-a-dbcontext-in-code-first

> How can I "inject" my model classes into the DbContext class at
>   runtime like when I register views and viewmodels with UnityContainer?

T4 idea here is similar, you generate your DbContext with all DbSets from the existing classes(Model):

This apporach will extend the DbConext and adding the "Model" folder with classes **dynamically(Reflection)** in **Complie Time**.

1) With T4 generate your DbContext class

2) With reflection load your Model entities (retrieve the model class names which you can use them to create the DbSets in the step 3)

3) With T4 generate the DbSets from the loaded entities(step 2) and adding them to the DbContext

[Optionally] 
If you want to generete the entities and the DbContext with T4 then, you can take a look to this project.

https://github.com/coni2k/DbContextGeneratorWithCodeFirst